# Noun used as an adjective but with some specification

Tags: word-order

On my database I have a variable which indicates if a certain counterparty migrated from a performing status to a default one.

Which description is correct:

> Transition flag to default status

or

> Transition to default status flag

or

what else?

Comment: Are you looking for the name of a variable? e.g. *default_status_flag* It is not at all clear.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK No, not the name of the variable, its description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of those two options, only the second one is correct.  We "transition to" something but there is no such thing as a "flag to" something.

As for other suggestions, does this flag indicate that a transition has already happened, or that a transition needs to happen later?

If the transition has already happened, you might want to name the column "Transition**ed** to default status flag."  If it has not yet transitioned, you could call it "Needs to transition to default status flag."  I find that kind of clarity really useful, but that's more a comment amount how to write code, not how to write English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree with Juhasz now that I understand it better.

I'm not sure what the difference is between a meaningful variable-name and its description.

So ***transitioned_to_default_status*** **flag**, could be both the name and the description.

Comment: Thank you! The name is `FLG_DEF`, the description explains what the variable means.